# Azure Data Studio set tab as delimiter when exporting a csv

Tags: csv, azure-data-studio

in Azure Data Studio there's a setting called `queryEditor.results.saveAsCsv.delimiter` that allows the user to choose the default delimiter when exporting query results in a csv file. However, I'm struggling to find a way to set this property to use a tab as a delimiter; i tried `\t`, but it seem that the property only accepts 1 single character, so it considers only `\`. I searched a lot and couldn't find any solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're placing the escaped character in double quotes

```
"queryEditor.results.saveAsCsv.delimiter": "\t",
```

I don't think it accepts one character, I wanted my CSV exports to have a record for each line so my line separator needs be CRLF on a Windows machine. It's set to:

```
"queryEditor.results.saveAsCsv.lineSeperator": "\r\n",
```

Comment: Hi Jorge, I was already cheering for the solution, but having a better look it seems that it doesn't work. Using `"\t"` (with double quotes) leads to the creation of a csv with `"` (one double quote) as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behavior as @BobbyRoode. If I type `\t` or `"\t"` in the Settings dialog, it only uses the first character as a delimiter. I worked around it by copying a TAB in another app (Emacs, in my case) and pasting it into the Settings dialog and that worked.